# Smarty - template definition inside template

Tags: php, smarty

Lets say we have 3 arrays with mysql records, for example:

- Pending orders
- Processing orders
- Last 20 shipped orders

I want to show the data as HTML table for all cases, so I will make a new TPL called "order-table.tpl" and via parameter i will send mysql rows data to the template file. I can call it as this:

```
{include file="order-table.tpl" rows=$pending_rows}
{include file="order-table.tpl" rows=$processing_rows}
{include file="order-table.tpl" rows=$last_shipped_rows}
```

This example works it creates 3 tables with correct data, but is there any other way to define template file inside template file? I don't want to make a new TPL file every time. I would like to create some definition inside TPL file and later call it multiple times.

Comment: You could put your order arrars into a new array. Then iterate through it, creating a new table every time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [creating function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl) is the right solution.
You can create function this way:

```
{function name="hello" nickname="Mr. Unknown"}
    Hello, {$nickname}!
{/function}
```

And call it this way:

```
{call hello nickname="Manny"}
```

It works exactly the same as templates but you don't have to define it in a new file.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would rather stay at first solution. This is the most natural solution using Smarty. You create file and can include it anywhere you want. What will happen if you decide you want to use this code inside another template file? Probably you will have to copy this code into another file or eventually you do the same you had at the beginning - create file and copy content to it.

Creating multiple files is the normal thing when you develop application and in my opinion there is no reason to avoid creating new files when the are necessary.

Comment: That's true but what if you want to have all templates for messages stored in the one TPL file (really different kind of messages)? Then this solution is very useful. You can call it almost the same as regular template but you're not forced to create new file. So you will create "messages.tpl" and for each "message template" you will create function.

Comment: You might my right. But I haven't used it this way. I usually have messages stored in PHP and in Smarty I just use them.